# Como transformar uma expressão matemática em linguagem C

Tags: c, matemática

Como posso transformá-la em linguagem C?

[image: Expressão matemática:]

Comment: Apenas tem de perceber como a função funciona, o seu raciocínio e reproduzi-lo em código. Não consigo ajudar mais, pois não percebo a função

Comment: Você pode nos dizer o que você tentou e quais problemas está tendo?

Answer (score 7):

A função M, que você coloca, é uma função real de duas variáveis reais, definida por colagem (a expressão usada para calcular M(MP,ML) depende dos valores de MP e ML).

Para uma função real, de duas variáveis reais, uma função C que modele tal função matemática pode ter como assinatura `float nome_da_funcao(float arg1, float arg2)`, onde `arg1` e `arg2` são as variáveis da função (no seu caso, `MP` e `ML`).

Dependendo da precisão desejada (número de casas decimais após a vírgula ou, em C, após o ponto), talvez fosse necessário usar `double`, mas, nesse caso particular, parece que `float` está de bom tamanho.

Como ela é definida por colagem, a expressão para devolver o seu valor calculado em (MP, ML) (ou, se você gostar de matematiquês, a imagem de (MP, ML)) depende de uma expressão condicional aplicada aos argumentos MP e ML. Bem, se a expressão usada para calcular o valor da função, no ponto (MP, ML), depende se MP e ML satisfazem certa condição, está claro que você terá de usar no seu código uma condicional, pelo menos, ou mais de uma, quando for o caso.

No caso da sua função:

se (MP < 5 ou ML < 5)

```c
M = Min{MP, ML}<br>
```

senão

```c
M = (7*MP + 3*ML)/10
```

Se você tiver uma função `Min(float x, float y)` disponível, o seu código pode ser

```c
float M(float MP, float ML)
{
    if((MP < 5.0)||(ML < 5.0))
        return Min(MP, ML)
    else
        return ((7*MP + 3*ML)/10);
}
```

Contudo, se não tiver `Min(float x, float y)`, pode usar

```c
float M(float MP, float ML)
{
    if((MP < 5.0)||(ML < 5.0))
    {
        if (MP <= ML)
            return MP;
        else
            return ML;
    }
    else
        return ((7*MP + 3*ML)/10);
}
```

ou definir

```c
float Min(float x, float y)
{
    if (x <= y)
        return x;
    else
        return y;
}
```

e, juntamente com essa função, usar o primeiro código.

Comment: +1 A resposta ficou muito boa! :)

Comment: Leonardo, tomei a liberdade de editar levemente sua postagem para quebrar um pouco os parágrafos, para facilitar a leitura. Só o fiz pelo fato de você poder reverter a edição, se entender que ela não lhe agradar. Para reverter basta clicar em [edit] e no link "reverter" acima da versão desejada. Para ver as alterações feitas, basta [este link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/90605/revisions). Quanto ao conteúdo, já levou meu +1

Answer (score -2):

O programa completo fica assim:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
    double mp, ml;
    printf("Digite o Mp: ");
    scanf("%d",&mp);
    printf("\nDigite o Ml: ");
    scanf("%d",&ml);
    while(mp<5 || ml<5){
        printf("\nMp ou Ml menor que 5,0. Digite o numero novamente");
        printf("Digite o Mp: ");
        scanf("%d",&mp);
        printf("\nDigite o Ml: ");
        scanf("%d",&ml);
    }
    int m;
    //função:
    m=(7*mp+3*ml)/10;
    printf("%d", m);
}
```

Comment: Não é para ter esse `while`. A função que está na pergunta permite valores de `MP` e `ML` menores que `5`, nesse caso o valor a ser retornado é o menor valor dentre os dois, ou seja, `min(MP, ML)`.

Comment: eh que eu não sou muito bom nessa parte da matematica, a única parte que eu entendi foi essa: (7*mp+3*ml)/10, o resto eu supus que mp e ml tem que ser menores que 5, e olhando bem o codigo acho que fiz errado ainda kkk

Comment: Como já mencionaram, essa resposta está errada. Se você não entende a parte da matemática, sugiro removê-la (até para evitar receber negativos de bobeira). :)